# why is mongodb not indexing my collection

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have created a collection and added just a name field and tried to apply the following index.

```
db.names.createIndex({"name":1})
```

Even after applying the index I see the below result.
db.names.find()

> { "_id" : ObjectId("57d14139eceab001a19f7e82"), "name" : "kkkk" } {
>   "_id" : ObjectId("57d1413feceab001a19f7e83"), "name" : "aaaa" } {
>   "_id" : ObjectId("57d14144eceab001a19f7e84"), "name" : "zzzz" } {
>   "_id" : ObjectId("57d14148eceab001a19f7e85"), "name" : "dddd" } {
>   "_id" : ObjectId("57d1414ceceab001a19f7e86"), "name" : "rrrrr" }

What am I missing here.

Comment: are you expecting the sorted result, just by adding the indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Khans...

the way you built your index is correct however building an ascending index on names wont return the results in ascending order.

if you need results to be ordered by name you have to use

{db.names.find().sort({names:1})}

what happens when you build an index is that when you search for data the Mongo process perform the search behind the scenes in an ordered fashion for faster outcomes.

Please note: if you just want to see output in sorted order. you dont even need an index.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to see if an index has been successfully created (unless there is a considerable speed performance) by running a `find()` command.

Instead, use `db.names.getIndexes()` to see if the index has been created (it *may* take some time if you're running the index in the background for it to appear in the index list)

Comment: it was a typo in the question and I fixed it. I created the index with field "name" only, but it still does not work. I am on mongo 3.2

Comment: Try running `db.names.getIndexes()` and see if the index has been created.

Comment: Yes, the index is created.

Comment: ...so what's the issue?

Comment: My assumption was that, when i issue a find() command it is supposed to show the results in sorted order as per the index. But its not showing it until I issue a sort({"name":1}) specifically.

Comment: No, you need to supply the `sort()` to sort the result set. The index sort is so that MongoDB knows how to organise the index. See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/#create-an-ascending-index-on-a-single-field and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#index-types